# Fetch HTML file dynamically and display inside content place holder

Tags: html, asp.net, master-pages

I have a aspx page which is placed inside a master page. aspx page will read htm file and it should render on page load. I have written the following code in .cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmFile = Server.MapPath("../" + Session["ACCOUNT"] + "/HTMPage.htm");
            if (File.Exists(HtmFile))
            {
                Response.WriteFile(HtmFile);
            }

        }
```

HTM file getting rendered but it appears above the master page layout and not inside content place holder. To be clear in master page I have top menu and left menu user controls. My html is getting displayed above top menu. It should display inside content place holder. How can I achieve this? Is there any way that I can implement using java script?

Answer (score 0):

Modified code as follows:

Code behind:

```
  private string htmlfile = "";
            public string HTMLPageFile
            {
                get { return htmlfile; }
            }
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                htmlfile= Server.MapPath("../" + Session["ACCOUNT"] + "/HTMPage.htm");
            }
```

aspx:

```
<div id="htmlDiv">
            <% Response.WriteFile(HTMLPageFile); %>
        </div>
```